# Issue with monkeypatching

Tags: ruby, monkeypatching

I'm using Ruby 1.9.2-p180. The following piece of code throws the error:

> "test.rb:20:in `': undefined local variable or method `val' for main:Object (NameError)"

Is there a way that I could make the monkeypatching work to return `val`?

```
class Test
  def m
    "m"
  end
end

def inject(testObj, val)
  def testObj.m
    val
  end

  testObj
end


t = Test.new
puts t.m
puts inject(t, val).m
```

Answer (score 3):

The immediate problem is that in line 20 you are calling

```
puts inject(t, val).m
```

I.e. you are passing `val` as an argument to `inject`, but you never actually defined `val`. You need to pass an actual value, for example:

```
puts inject(t, 'Hello, World!').m
```

Or define `val` first:

```
val = 42
puts inject(t, val).m
```

However, if you do this, you will get a new error:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `val' for #<Test:0x007fa1228439b8>
```

The reason for this is that in Ruby, only blocks can be closures. Methods do not close over their surrounding lexical environment.

Which means that here:

```
def inject(testObj, val)
  def testObj.m
    val
  end

  testObj
end
```

you have

- an unused method argument `val` in `inject`
- a completely unrelated method call to a method named `val` in `testObj.m`

If you want to have access to the surrounding scope, you need to use a block. Thankfully, there is a (family of) methods that take blocks and define methods:

```
def inject(testObj, val)
  testObj.define_singleton_method(:m) do
    val
  end

  testObj
end
```

Now, everything works as expected:

```
puts inject(t, 'Hello, World!').m
# Hello, World!
```